# String joining with delimiter not working in Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to convert string array into string and join all values with delimiter (,) but it is adding only first two values, what is wrong in conversion code. Please see inline comments below

```
String[] array = new String[20];

for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++) {

   Log.d(TAG, "arrayvalue : " + array[i]); //Here I will get 5 values which is exact value count, but in next converted log I will have concatenation of only first two values, what is wrong in conversion code. 

   // Joining:
   StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
   for (String each : array)
        buffer.append(",").append(each);

   String joined = buffer.deleteCharAt(0).toString();

   Log.d("Prefs", "Converted Array to String : " + joined);

}
```

Comment: post the entire program and the result.

Comment: Your loop logic is flawed. Rethink your iterations.

Answer (score 2):

There is standard method for `String` join defined in Android SDK:

```
final String joined = TextUtils.join(",", array);
```

Comment: i will prefer this one

Comment: though it's a better way to convert, but it's not the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Use in dynamic array

```
String[] partno = new String[part.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < part.size(); i++){
        partno[i]=part.get(i).getText().toString();
        Hpartno= TextUtils.join(",",partno);

    }
```